# Unit testing OnResultExecuted

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

Has anybody tried unit testing OnResultExecuted method?

I have a simple controller that renders notification messages and then clears them.

```
public class NotificationController : BaseController
    {

        public NotificationController(INotificationMessagesContext notificationMessagesContext)
        {
            Contract.Requires<AppEx.NullArgumentException>(
                notificationMessagesContext != null, "Notification messages context must be set");

            notificationContext = notificationMessagesContext;
        }

        private readonly INotificationMessagesContext notificationContext;

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult Index()
        {
            return notificationContext == null ? null : PartialView(notificationContext.Messages);
        }


        protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (notificationContext != null && notificationContext.Messages.Any())
                notificationContext.ClearAll();

            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        }

    }
```

Unit testing Index() method won't be of any help, because OnResultExecuted is invoked by MVC. I can create a custom attribute that would be easily testable, but it seems like an overkill to implement a custom attribute for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would make an internal function that onresultexecuted calls, and then make internal functions available to the test project that uses them.

You can ignore the onresultexecuted then and test the internal function directly.

Here is a link to how to make internals visible to another project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx